# Bash Read line by line and replace string recursive

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have one file  whit multiple lines.Here example

**etc/list.txt**

```
MLA1234,MLA2345
MLA1235,MLA2345
```

I need to search recursive in folder search for this string and remplace. Example

**etc/json/other/file2.json**

```
{id:"MLA1234" , product_name:"blablabla"
```

Expected outpost whit replace string **MLA1234**

**etc/json/other/file2.json (final)**

```
{id:"MLA2345" , product_name:"blablabla"
```

I do something like this but has no match

```
#!/bin/bash

csvfile='list.txt'

# Make sure the file exists
if [ ! -f $csvfile ]
then
    echo "ERROR: file $csvfile does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Read the input file line per line
while read line
do

 # Capture the information out of the line, fields separated by ;
    IFS=',' read old new <<< $line



grep -rl $old . | xargs sed -i "s/$oldstring/$new/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thjis work for me! i fix the code!

````
#!/bin/bash

csvfile='list.txt'

# Make sure the file exists
if [ ! -f $csvfile ]
then
    echo "ERROR: file $csvfile does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Read the input file line per line
sed '1d' $csvfile | while read line
do
    # Capture the information out of the line, fields separated by ;
    IFS=',' read new old  <<< $line


grep -rl "$old" . | xargs sed -i "s/$old/$new/g"


done```
````